# ローカルで開発したwordpressサイトをGitlab上のレポジトリにアップして、テスト用のドメインでアクセス可能にしたいです。

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, gitlab

会社内で使用しているサーバーにGitlab上にアップしたwordpressファイルが何も表示されず、wp-admin, wp-login.phpにもアクセスできず、404 page not foundが表示されて解決できずに困っているので、アドバイス頂けると大変幸いです。

今までも他のプロジェクトで同じようにwordpressファイルをアップしてもこのような問題はなく、いくら調べても解決できません。。。先輩が有給でいないので、どなたかお力を貸して頂けると助かります。

***実現したいこと***
ローカルで開発したwordpressサイトをGitlab上のレポジトリにアップして、テスト用のドメインでアクセス可能にしたいです。

***現状***
ローカルMAMPで作成したwordpressサイトは正常に問題なく表示されている
ドメイン名はhttps://テーマ名.preview.sample.de/

オリジナルテーマを使用しています。
パスは、wp-content -> themes -> オリジナルテーマ -> index.php, front-page.php.. etc

***試したこと***
１）wp-config.phpに下記を追加 =>　Not Found
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);　//何もエラーは表示されない
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://テーマ名.preview.sample.de/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://テーマ名.preview.sample.de/' );

２）.htaccessを下記のように編集(RewriteBaseとRewriteRuleがそれぞれ２つ書いてありますが、どちらかをコメントアウトして試しましたが404が表示される) =>　Not Found

```
// 一部抜粋
BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /テーマ名/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /テーマ名/index.php [L]　
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

END WordPress
```

３）.htaccessを削除して、https://テーマ名.preview.sample.de/にアクセス => Not Found

URLが何らかの原因で存在してないか、もしくは.htaccessの書き方が問題だと考えているですが、もし他に考えられる原因がありましたら、コメントしてくださると嬉しいです。
スクショはGitlab上にアップしたwordpressファイル全てです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
[image: アップロードしたファイル]
[image: アップロードしたファイル]

この質問は[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/365376)でもさせていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

GitLab はあくまで「バージョン管理システム = ファイルのストレージ」であり、ここにいくらファイルをアップロードしても WordPress (PHP) はプログラムとして動作しません。

WordPress を動作させるには、Web サーバ (Apache, Nginx など) が管理する領域にファイルをアップロードする必要があると思います。

Answer (score 0):

Gitのフックを使って自動的に展開（デプロイ）することは可能ですが
GitLabのリポジトリ内のcustom_hooksに　post-receiveファイルを作成しシェルスクリプトを書く権限と、file copyするシェルスクリプトが書けることが必要です。